# What is error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, fetch-api

Failed to load resource:

> net::**ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED?**

Comment: show please some code, like if you call an api .. ?

Comment: please add more details, what is the backened, how you trying to connect, when it is throwing this error??

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what it says.

You tried to connect to something over the network. The system you were connecting to refused to accept the connection.

Usually this is because there isn't a service listening on the port you tried to connect to. Sometimes the connection is blocked by a firewall.